# schematic errors in eagle regarding vcc and vdd

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

Hello somebody there ?

Can someone explain to me why VDD is connected to VCC directly ? Call me stupid but this cant be right . I hope I am stupid and to be able to learn something out of this :+1: Came on the schematic as soon as I did ERC and came as an error I tought ok maybe nothing severe ... maybe a warning but can this be valid ?

greets[image]

Comment: Could you give more information, like where did the schematic came from, what is the schematic for or attach the full schematic.

Comment: Did you make the component highlighted? From the warning, basically the 'type' on the Vdd pin is set to 'sup', whereas it should be set to 'pwr'. If you open the symbol and go to the properties of the pin, you can change its type.

Comment: In fact it seems there are quite a few pins around your schematic assigned the wrong type.

Comment: hy, they are both set on NET CLASS 1-power

Comment: yeah I found it on the net LOL ... is this intentionaly done or is this just lack of information and ignoring stuff ... I dont know

Comment: If someone used the 'sup' option, it's because of being misinformed. The VDD arrow symbols (and the GND symbols) are the only ones which should be set to 'sup' - it basically means replace this net by a supply net with the same name. The 'pwr' option says, connect me to a power supply.

Comment: Generally speaking, VDD is V+ for digital circuits (using MOSFETS--"D" stands for "Drain") and VCC is V+ for analog circuits (using BJTs--"C" stands for "Collector"). Once again this is a very general statement, but it should get the point across. They are both V+.

Comment: Thank you all,

How do I change a net in eagle ? Im new to it ..
But in the end there is nothing wrong with it right ? 
Those are just protocols errors right ?

greets

Comment: TOm Carpenter can you help me with something ? I can even pay you if you wish, I need this cleaned and I wanted to do some improvements. If its ok with you please give me your email address or something I can contact you to provide you with the details. greets Alex

Comment: Why is there an Altium tag ?

Answer (score 1):

### They both mean "V+"

As @derstrom8 noted, they are both conventional labels for the positive power supply, *just from different conventions*. It turns out that these terms are borrowed from transistor technology as follows:

[image]

[Solarbotics](http://encyclobeamia.solarbotics.net/articles/vxx.html) has a nice summary article, which I reproduced here:

### Background

These notations are used in describing voltages at various common power supply terminals (at these points, only a wire lead exists between the point and a power source) of a given circuit.

Apparently this terminology originated in some way from the terminals of each type of transistor, and their common connections in logic circuits (i.e., Vcc is often applied to BJT collectors, Vee to BJT emitters, Vdd to FET drains, and Vss to FET sources). This notation then carries across to integrated circuits -- TTL ICs were originally based on BJT technology, and so often use the Vcc / Vee terminology; CMOS ICs are based on FET technology, and so often use the Vdd / Vss terminology.

### Used interchangeably now

The absolute distinctions between these common supply terms has since been blurred by the interchangeable application of TTL and CMOS logic families. Most CMOS (74HC / AC, etc.) IC data sheets now use Vcc and Gnd to designate the positive and negative supply pins.